Шейдерная программа OpenGL перестала прикреплять к себе шейдеры
Во время переноса библиотеки из заголовочной в простую (сборка через cmake, тип *.a) у меня возникла проблема. После переноса класса Program, появилась ошибка error: no shaders attached to the program. Вот старая реализация класса програм (покажу только изменения) и новая реализация, а также класс шейдер. Код:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

const GLchar* shader1 = "#version 460 core\nout vec4 FragColor;\nvoid main() { FragColor = vec4(1.0); }";
const GLchar* shader2 = "#version 460 core\nvoid main() { gl_Position = vec4(1.0); }";

#define LogSize 1024

// class Shader
class Shader
{
  public:
    GLuint shader;
    Shader(GLenum type, const GLchar* source)
    {
        shader = glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        GLint error = 0; GLchar log[LogSize];
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &error);
        if (error == GL_FALSE)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, LogSize, NULL, log);
            printf("%s", log);
        }
    }
    void del() { glDeleteShader(shader); }
};

class Program
{
  public:
    GLuint ID;
    Program(vector<Shader> &shaders);
    Program(Shader* shaders, size_t len);
};

// new class Program
Program::Program(vector<Shader> &shaders)
{
    ID = glCreateProgram();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < shaders.size(); i++) glAttachShader(ID, shaders[i].shader);
    glLinkProgram(ID);

    GLint error = 0; GLchar log[LogSize]; // LogSize = 1024
    glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &error);
    if (error == GL_FALSE) 
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ID, LogSize, NULL, log);
        printf("%s", log);
    }
}
// old class Program
Program::Program(Shader* shaders, size_t len)
{
    ID = glCreateProgram();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) glAttachShader(ID, shaders[i].shader);
    glLinkProgram(ID);

    GLint error = 0; GLchar log[LogSize]; // LogSize = 1024
    glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &error);
    if (error == GL_FALSE) 
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ID, LogSize, NULL, log);
        printf("%s", log);
    }
 }

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* win, int a, int b) {}
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow*, double a, double b) {}
void processInput(GLFWwindow* win) {}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(400, 400, "", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) 
    {
       std::cout << "Fail to create window!";
       glfwTerminate();
       return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
         std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            
 
    // main
    Shader shader1(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "path to shader");
    Shader shader2(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "path to shader");

    // new program
    vector<Shader> shaders = {shader1, shader2};
    Program program(shaders);
    // old program
    Shader shaders2[] = {shader1, shader2};
    Program program2(shaders2, 2);

    // и в старой и в новой
    shader1.del();
    shader2.del();
}

Как видно, код почти не поменялся, но теперь при возвращении к старой версии ничего не работает. Помогите пожалуйста, я не пойму почему оно перестало работать и небольшое уточнение, я использую glad, glfw3 и OpenGL 4.6. Вот команда для компиляции ```g++ (или любой другой компилятор) main.cpp -o main -I путь_к_заголовкам_glfw3_и_glad -L путь_к_библиотека_glfw3_и_glad -lglad -lglfw3

Дежавю. Этот вопрос уже был вчера. И в новом вместо того, чтобы привести [mcve], по-прежнему приведены какие-то обрывки кода... "покажу только изменения" - а надо было привести такой пример, который читатели вопроса могли бы запустить у себя и получать заявленную вами ошибку. Подобные вопросы без такого примера на этом сайте являются оффтопиком.

Вы насчёт каких обрывков? Я показал конструктор и старый и новый в программе, читать файл не сложно, в main есть код, который создаёт шейдеры и программу. Если вы про отсуствие шейдеров, то подходят любый, так-как они не присоеденяются к программе, а значит их нельзя использовать. Да и я указал что в старом конструкторе изменились только аргументы и цикл for, всё остальное без изменений

Указал main и тип ID, создание окна не относится к этому вопросу (любое окно, и GLFW, и FreeGlut и WinApi и т.д), также не относится что и как рисовать, потому что ещё до этапа отрисоки выходит ошибка.

@jdoseIOO, я вам уже дал ссылку на статью, вы ее не прочитали видимо, вот у меня например нет времени что-то там искать, выдумывать как мне инициализацировать OpenGL, Window, и т.д. чтобы решить ваш вопрос это займет уйму времени, приводите пример, без лишнего кода, инициализация окна, контекста OpenGL, загрузка расширений, и попытка создать Program, с вашим шейдером, который так же тут отсутствует, какие-то обрывки кодов класса, которые не полные, и догадываться что у вас там ещё есть, и что вы вызываете, это не наше дело, хотите ответ, и решение будьте добры приложить все необходимое.

Создание окна не обязательно, как и отрисовка. В этом примере будет уже есть ошибка, я покажу только создание окна. Отрисовка не нужна, до неё ошибка! Шейдер вставляйте какой хотите, что угодно. Так как программа просто его не подключает к себе, в итоге любой шейдер не работает

Такое ощущение, что выложенный в вопросе код вы даже не пытались сами запускать. Ведь иначе вы бы увидели, что при попытке сборки он выдаст ошибку про "необъявленный идентификатор GLuint". Заметьте, что в вопросе решают проблему не с тем кодом, который есть у вас, а с тем, который представлен в вопросе.

Я писал что использую glad, и GLuint в glad как раз определён, если у вас нету glad и glfw3 то ничего не соберётся

@jdoseIOO, пожалуйста! Не усложняйте себе решение проблемы вставкой непонятных some func read, на уточняющие комментарии действуйте так чтобы вы могли удовлетворить того кто вас что-то просит добавить в вопрос для его решения, от того что вы будете спорить в комментариях как вам удобно или что-то ещё, что вы не будете то или иное выкладывать т.к. оно не относится к проблеме, это не ускорит его решение а только оттолкнет людей от возможно заинтересованности в его решении, будьте так добры, приложите полный код ваших классов Program, Shader, включая заголовочные файлы которые вы используете.

Какой ещё исходный код вы хотите от меня, у программы отсуствуют только передача переменных в шейдер и использование её, они не нужна в данном вопросе и я накинул бесполезных шейдеров в код. Они подойдут. И какие ещё заголовки? (iostream есть, glad и glfw есть, что ещё нужно?) Если вы про исходники, то они есть на официальных сайтах, да и компилировать их нужно для каждой системы отдельно. Только уточню, я использую glfw3 динамический, а glad статический

... Ну посмотрите вы на этот код... Вы понимаете что там отсутствуют переменные которые используются? Это раз, два: вечно разные какие-то куски кода не связанные с тем что вас просят в комментариях выложить полностью код .cpp файла, и его заголовка? Я голосую за закрытие, по причине нет минимального воспроизводимого кода для отладки. А про заголовочные файлы, это инструкции препроцессора #include

Пример сейчас воспроизводим, и посмотри код, там есть #include

Очевидно, что вы просто копипастите в вопрос какие-то куски из своего проекта, ни разу не убидившись, не только в том, что приведенный код реально воспроизводит проблему, а хотя бы в том, что код вообще собирается.

Я не могу привести 100% исходного кода, так-как он является закрытым. Я показываю пример запуска и часть исходного кода, в которой и содержится ошибка. А у вас точно есть нужные зависимости для сборки?

Да никому не нужен полностью ваш код, вас просят 2 класса показать в нормальном виде! Шейдер, и программа... Все, больше ничего

Я скопировал 1 и тот же код из нововерсии в старую

Если установить все зависимости, то код должен собраться. К сожалению я сейчас не имею доступ к исходному коду, поэтому я воиспроизвожу новые изменения по памяти, скажите пожалуйста о ошибках компиляции если таковые есть.

Такое ощущение, что по приведенной в первом комментарии ссылке [mcve] вы даже не переходили. Потому что первый же пункт там Начните с нуля. Создайте новую программу, куда войдет только то, что необходимо, и речи про выкладывание 100% исходного кода вашего начального проекта (который выкладывать в любом случае не стоит, так как мало кому захочется в нем копаться) не идет.

Всё, я получил доступ к основной системе. Я жутко извиняюсь за предоставленный код. У меня небыло возможности его проверить и я его писал с гитхаба и телефона. Теперь точно всё работает (воиспроизводитя ошибка тоесть)

ОК, теперь сразу бросается в глаза, что поле GLuint shader; остается неинициализированным. В коде не видно ни одного вызова glCreateShader, где мог бы создаваться шейдер (по аналогии с glCreateProgram). Кроме того, отсутствует код обработки ошибок. После каждого вызова функции opengl, устанавливающей глобальное значение ошибки (т.е. практически всех) должен сразу следовать вызов glGetError. После glShaderSource оно бы наверяняка вернуло GL_INVALID_VALUE, так как переданный дескриптор шейдера невалидный.

насчёт glCreateShader я просто забыл его добавить в припер, а насчёт glGetError я впервые слышу. Можете пожалуйста кинуть статью об этом

Спасибо, но есть проблема. Исходный код слишком объёмный и проблема не решена. После исправления очевидных ошибок в примере проблема исчезла. Но в исходном коде шейдеры правильные(glGetError() возвращает 0, а в примере они были с ошибкой) но проблема не решилась в исходном. Я если вы не против хотел бы с кем то из вас связаться. Я использую дискорд

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Спасибо @evo, после его слов "Копирование ресурсов видеокарты, включая шейдеры, не возможна, нельзя копировать класс шейдера, он должен быть уникальным, как и класс программы, у вас быть может удаляется шейдер в деструкторе, и после этого он не пригоден для использования". После его слов я решил изменить свой код. Как было раньше(с ошибкой):
// класс Program
Program::Program(vector<Shader> shaders);

// в main
vector<Shader> shaders = {shader1, shader2, ...};
Program program(shaders);

И это был ошибочный вариант. Я передавал в программу не ссылку на шейдер, а копию шейдера, из-за этого вызывался деструктор который удалял шейдер из памяти видеокаты.
В новом варианте я передаю ссылку на шейдер, поэтому деструктор не вызывается.
Как сейчас(без ошибки):
// класс Program
Program::Program(vector<Shader*> &shaders);

// в main
vector<Shader*> shaders = {&shader1, &shader2, ...};
Program program(shaders);

Теперь ошибки нет, спасибо за помощь @evo.

Ладно, после стольких попыток ТС все таки дополнил код, что бы можно было предположить что там не так, однако, хочу сказать сразу, что проблема не воспроизвелась, быть может снова, ТС что-то скрывает, и не договаривает.
Написал рабочий код:
main.cxx:
#include <vector>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <open/gl/shader.hxx>
#include <open/gl/program.hxx>
#include <open/gl/vertex_shader.hxx>
#include <open/gl/fragment_shader.hxx>

static std::string fragment_source
  = "#version 460 core\nout vec4 FragColor;\nvoid main() { FragColor = vec4(1.0); }";

static std::string vertex_source
  = "#version 460 core\nvoid main() { gl_Position = vec4(1.0); }";

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  glfwInit();

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Some Window", NULL, NULL);
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);

  std::vector<open::gl::shader *> shaders {
    new open::gl::vertex_shader(vertex_source),
    new open::gl::fragment_shader(fragment_source))
  };

  open::gl::program program(shaders);

  for (open::gl::shader *shader : shaders) {
    delete shader;
  }

  shaders.clear();
}

shader.hxx:
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <glad/glad.h>

namespace open::gl {
  struct shader {
    using handle = ::GLuint;

    handle id() const;

    ~shader();

    shader(shader &&other);
    shader(shader const &) = delete;
    shader &operator =(shader &&other);
    shader &operator =(shader const &) = delete;

  protected:
    enum class type {
      vertex = GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
      fragment = GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
    };

    shader(shader::type type);
    shader(shader::type type, std::filesystem::path const &path);
    shader(shader::type type, std::string const &src);

    void set_source(std::string const &src) const;
    void compile();

  private:
    handle m_handle_;
  };
} // namespace open::gl

shader.cxx:
#include "shader.hxx"
#include "utils.hxx"
#include <utility>

namespace open::gl {
  shader::handle
  shader::id() const {
    return m_handle_;
  }

  shader::~shader() {
    glDeleteShader(m_handle_);
  }

  shader::shader(shader &&other)
    : m_handle_(std::exchange(other.m_handle_, 0))
  { }

  shader
  &shader::operator=(shader &&other) {
    if (&other != this) {
      m_handle_ = std::exchange(other.m_handle_, 0);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  shader::shader(shader::type type)
    : m_handle_{glCreateShader(static_cast<GLuint>(type))} {
    if (!glIsShader(m_handle_)) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create shader");
    }
  }

  shader::shader(shader::type type, std::filesystem::path const &path)
      : shader(type, utils::path_to_content(path))
  { }

  shader::shader(shader::type type, std::string const &src)
    : shader(type) {
    set_source(src);
    compile();
  }

  void
  shader::set_source(std::string const &src) const {
    GLchar const *data = src.data();
    GLint data_size = src.length();
    glShaderSource(m_handle_, 1, &data, &data_size);
  }

  void
  shader::compile() {
    glCompileShader(m_handle_);
    // need some more checks for error's call glGetError()

    GLint has_compiled {};
    glGetShaderiv(m_handle_, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &has_compiled);

    if (GL_TRUE != has_compiled) {
      GLint error_size {};
      glGetShaderiv(m_handle_, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &error_size);
      std::string error_message(static_cast<size_t>(error_size + 1), '\0');
      glGetShaderInfoLog(m_handle_, error_size, nullptr, error_message.data());
      glDeleteShader(m_handle_);
      m_handle_ = 0;
      throw std::runtime_error("Shader failed to compile with reason: " + error_message);
    }
  }
} // namespace open::gl

program.hxx:
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <glad/glad.h>

namespace open::gl {
  struct shader;

  struct program {
    using handle = GLuint;

    program();
    program(shader const &shader);
    program(std::vector<open::gl::shader *> const &shaders);

    handle id() const;
    void attach(open::gl::shader const &shader);
    void link() const;

    program(program && other) noexcept;
    program(program const &other) = delete;

    program &operator =(program const &other) = delete;
    program &operator =(program &&other) noexcept;

  private:
    handle m_handle_;
  };
} // namespace open::gl

program.cxx:
#include "program.hxx"
#include "shader.hxx"
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace open::gl {
  program::program()
    : m_handle_(glCreateProgram()) {
    // error checking...
  }

  program::program(open::gl::shader const &shader)
    : program() {
    attach(shader);
    link();
  }

  program::program(std::vector<open::gl::shader *> const &shaders)
    : program() {
    for (open::gl::shader const *shader : shaders) {
      attach(*shader);
    }

    link();
  }

  program::handle
  program::id() const {
    return m_handle_;
  }

  void program::attach(open::gl::shader const &shader) {
    glAttachShader(m_handle_, shader.id());
    // error checking...
  }

  void program::link() const {
    glLinkProgram(m_handle_);
    GLint compile_status {};

    glGetProgramiv(m_handle_, GL_LINK_STATUS, &compile_status);

    if (!compile_status) {
      size_t log_length {};
      glGetProgramiv(m_handle_, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,
                     reinterpret_cast<GLint *>(&log_length));
      if (log_length > 0) {
        std::string error_message(log_length, '\0');
        glGetProgramInfoLog(m_handle_, log_length, nullptr, error_message.data());
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to link program with reason :" + error_message);
      }
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to link program with unknown reason");
    }
  }

  program::program(program &&other) noexcept
    : m_handle_(std::exchange(other.m_handle_, 0))
  { }

  program
  &program::operator =(program &&other) noexcept {
    if (&other != this) {
      m_handle_ = std::exchange(other.m_handle_, 0);
    }

    return *this;
  }

} // namespace open::gl

fragment_shader.hxx:
#pragma once

#include "shader.hxx"

namespace open::gl {
  struct fragment_shader
    : public shader {
    fragment_shader(std::string const &src);
    fragment_shader(std::filesystem::path const &path);
  };
} // namespace open::gl

fragment_shader.cxx:
#include "fragment_shader.hxx"

namespace open::gl {
  fragment_shader::fragment_shader(std::string const &src)
    : shader(shader::type::fragment, src)
  { }

  fragment_shader::fragment_shader(std::filesystem::path const &path)
    : shader(shader::type::fragment, path)
  { }
} // namespace open::gl

vertex_shader.hxx:
#pragma once

#include "shader.hxx"

namespace open::gl {
  struct vertex_shader
    : public shader {
    vertex_shader(std::string const &src);
    vertex_shader(std::filesystem::path const &path);
  };
} // namespace open::gl

vertex_shader.cxx:
#include "vertex_shader.hxx"

namespace open::gl {
  vertex_shader::vertex_shader(std::string const &src)
    : shader(shader::type::vertex, src)
  { }

  vertex_shader::vertex_shader(std::filesystem::path const &path)
    : shader(shader::type::vertex, path)
  { }
} // namespace open::gl

utils.hxx:
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace open::gl::utils {
  std::string
  path_to_content(std::filesystem::path const &path) {
    try {
      std::ifstream resource(path.string());
      std::streamsize file_length
        = resource
            .seekg(0, std::ios::end)
            .tellg();
      resource.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
      std::string content(file_length, '\0');
      resource.read(content.data(), file_length);
      return content;
    } catch (std::iostream::failure const &ex) {
      std::cerr << "Failed to open input file: " << ex.what() << '\n';
      throw;
    }
  }
} // namespace open::gl::utils


Это конечно хороший ход, вполне читабелен (не для меня, я к сожалению не так хорошо владею c++, поэтому сложно читать), но у меня проблема с компиляцией вашего кода, а точнее файла main.cxx. У меня стоят все библиотеки, компилятор ссылается на неправильный синтаксис. Скажите пожалуйста какой стандарт вы использовали для этого кода, так-как не c++11, c++17, c++20 не подходят. И у меня есть поддержка OpenGL 4.6

я хотел бы чтобы вы зашли в чат

C++ 17 можно использовать, там библиотека filesystem, и nested namespace
